# Infinite loop instead of moving onto next folder

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to make a library function where using a JSON file (created by [directory tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/directory-tree)), where it digs into each folder, to then build up an interactive `<ul>` list.  I'm testing it out via console, where it loops infinitely in folder `json` (as per this example).

[My json file](https://gist.github.com/alice-em/8c3a30df190df73433905d495b7a5713)

My code is as follows ...

```
var directory = './app';
var jSon = dirTree(directory, ['.js', '.json', '.html']);

console.log(jSon.children.length)

libBuilder(directory, jSon.children)

function libBuilder(directory, array) {
  for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (fs.statSync(path.join(directory, array[i].name)).isFile()) {
      console.log(colors.cyan(array[i].name))
    } else if ( fs.statSync(path.join(directory, array[i].name)).isDirectory()) {
      console.log(colors.red(array[i].name));
      libBuilder(path.join(directory, array[i].name), array[i].children)
    }
  };
}
```

This console output repeats indefinitely:

```
 json
 comic.json
 config.json
 library.json
 dragscroll.js
 file.js
```

How do I fix up the code to where it reads everything in a folder than then moves out to check the next time in the object array?

Comment: What is executing this script? It seems whatever is calling it would be stuck in an infinite loop and not this code.

Comment: It is me testing out code via `node treeTest.js`

Comment: `for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) {` <-- `i` is global! `var` is NOT optional or you run into bugs like this.

Comment: Wow!  Super easy!  Epascarello, put it in an answer and I'll mark you as correct.

Comment: This is a good candidate for adding immutability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i=0; i < array.length; i++) { <-- i is global!
```

You need to define `i` with `var` so it is not global. Each time you call it, it gets reset to zero on each iteration.

```
for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
```